# Array macro definition

Tags: c, r, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to define a `macro` to convert `2D array` syntax to `1D vector`. i.e., for a `12x12` array, `matrix[i,j]` should evaluate to `matrix[12*i + j]`. So far I have tried

```
#define matrix[i,j] matrix[12*i+j]

#define (matrix[i,j]) matrix[12*i+j]

#define matrix[(i,j)] matrix[12*i+j]

#define matrix([i,j]) matrix[12*i+j]`
```

The reason I am using `matrix[i,j]` syntax is because it will be an extension to be called from R code, and I would like the other authors of the project to understand exactly what is being done. Is there a way to do this with a macro?

Comment: Why a macro?  I would think this is function territory, esp. if you're talking about exposing it to something else.  Remember macros are pre-processor time only.

Comment: Don't use macros. They are evil.

Comment: Why are you even doing that? What's wrong with the normal [][] syntax?

Comment: I rather suspect that "other authors" will be more, not less, confused if you take this approach.  Why aren't you creating your data objects as matrices in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The only way that you can do is with `( )` and not with `[]`

```
#define matrix(i,j) matrix[12*i+j]
```

and in the code, you define matrix in this way

```
int matrix[12*12];
matrix(i,j) = 5;
```

Comment: How can that work. The macro will expand both instances of `matrix`.

Comment: I checked with `gcc -E` and no problemwith that

Comment: Code generated with `gcc -E`: `int main()
{
    int matrix[12*12];
    matrix[12*1 +1] = 15;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work:

```
#define TO_1D(m,x,y) (m[x*12+y])

int matrix[100];
TO_1D(matrix, 0, 4) = 13;
```

but I wonder why you don't prefer something safer like:

```
int data[100];
inline int& matrix(int x, int y)
{
   return data[x*12+y];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to only define a macro for the calculation, not the dereferencing.

```
#define X_DIM 12
#define Y_DIM 12
#define D21(x,y) (X_DIM*(x)+(y))

int my_matrix1[X_DIM*Y_DIM];
double my_matrix2[X_DIM*Y_DIM];

my_matrix1[D21(4, 3)];
my_matrix2[D21(2, 1)];
```

So you are not limited to the unique matrix defined in your macro.

More fundamentally, why are you even trying to do that? The normal multidimensional array syntax is already there to do exactly that.